# Excel Empty range if day falls on weekend/holiday

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro that empties the range of cells below the date if it is a Sunday or holiday based on the list of dates I have. Any idea how best to do this?

E.G. K33:Z33 are dates. If K33 is a sunday, K34:K100 = 0 instead of a value that was input by another macro.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could `Weekday()` function and write such a "helper" Sub:

```
Sub FillRange(val As Variant)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim valToFillWith As Variant

    For Each cell In Range("K33:Z33")
        If Weekday(cell.Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
            valToFillWith = 0
        Else
            valToFillWith = val
        End If
        cell.Offset(1).Resize(67).Value = valToFillWith
    Next
End Sub
```

to be exploited in your "Main" sub as follows:

```
Sub Main()

    '...
    ' your "macro" code before filling the range
    '...

    FillRange "myMacroValue"

    ' your "macro" code fater filling the range
    '...

End Sub
```

Comment: @archh, if my answer solves your question then please accept it by   clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Comment: that was ABSOLUTELY what I was trying to do! Thank you so much and hope u have a great day!

Comment: you are welcome